# How to determine if a field is under validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

[jQuery Validat(e/tion)](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

I've got a custom datepicker widget which I want to validate using jQuery.validate. When I modify my date it doesn't revalidate, presumably because the change event isn't firing on underlying hidden to which jQuery.validate is bound.

Through my research I've found that I can revalidate a single field by calling `$('#mydatepicker').valid()`. I can put this in the on-change handler of my custom widget.

In theory, this should work, but my widget's on-change event fires once before jQuery.validation is initialized. This seems to break jQuery.validate completely.

So I'm looking for a way to determine if jQuery.validate has been initialized for this particular element. i.e., to determine if jQuery.validate is attempting to watch it.

I tried

```
if($input.valid) $input.valid();
```

But I think the method exists regardless if jQuery.validate has been initialized yet.

---

To be clear, the structure of my HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="mywidget" type="hidden">
    <script>$('#mywidget').initializeMyCustomWidget();</script>
</form>
<script>
    $('#myform').validate({ myOptions });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I took a peek at what the `.valid` method actually does. It runs this:

```
$( this[ 0 ].form ).validate()
```

i.e. if you haven't called `.validate()` yet then it's going to apply an empty validator to your form, with whatever default rules apply. This is why it was breaking my form.

The only way I could figure out how to check if my form already has a validator is by checking if the form has the data property `validator`. I'm not sure how reliable this is.

I wrote this jQuery extension to "maybe" validate a specific field.

```
/**
 * Validate inputs iff the form has a validator.
 */
$.fn.maybeValidate = function() {
    var valid = true;
    this.each(function() {
        if(this.form && $(this.form).data('validator')) {
            valid = $(this).valid() && valid;
        }
    });
    return valid;
}
```

This works great for my use case because I can just call that method inside all my widget onchange callbacks. If a validator is bound, it'll revalidate the field. If not, no harm done.

Comment: Again, the reason you even need to do this is unclear.  Why you cannot simply initialize the validate plugin before you initialize the widget that depends on it is also unclear.  In answering over a thousand questions about this plugin, I have never seen anyone with your situation.  Something is very strange here.

Comment: @Sparky I responded to your comment under your answer. I don't want to delay the initialization of my widgets. Plus it would be a major refactor to do so. I've got little macros that writes out all the HTML for the widget *and* the script to initialize it; it's hard to separate the two.

Answer (score -1):

> But I think the method exists regardless if jQuery.validate has been initialized yet.

You cannot use `.valid()` before `.validate()` is initialized.

However, since one would typically initialize `.validate()` on DOM ready, this should never be an issue.

[Documentation states:](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

> `.validate()` needs to be called on the form before checking it using this method.

---

> So I'm looking for a way to determine if jQuery.validate has been initialized for this particular element. i.e., to determine if jQuery.validate is attempting to watch it.

Simply initialize the plugin on DOM ready so it can "watch" the form for triggering events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        // rules, options, etc.
    });

});
```

Comment: "Not true. You cannot use .valid() before .validate() is initialized." -- "method exists" and "can use" are two very different things. The library defines .valid() but that doesn't mean it's safe to use. My point was that checking for existence isn't sufficient. "Simply initialize" -- I don't understand how this solves my problem at all. My widget is initialized **before** `$('#myform').validate()` is called, and `.valid()` doesn't work in that context. This is the problem.

Comment: @Mark, then why can't you call `.validate()` ***before*** you initialize your widget that depends on `.valid()`?

Comment: Because of how my form is built. The widgets are initialized immediately after the `<input>`. And I like it that way; why would I want to delay instantiation? `.validate()` OTOH can't happen until after `</form>` AFAIK.

Comment: @Mark, *"Because of how my form is built."* ~ perhaps for the education and benefit of other readers, you could improve your OP so that it's more clear.  A MCVE would be great.  Five thousand SO questions about this plugin and your case is truly unique.

Comment: I wrote it quite plainly in my question: "my widget's on-change event fires once before jQuery.validation is initialized". A MCVE doesn't make sense here -- there's too much extraneous stuff.

Comment: @Mark, yes... and I'm just wondering why an `onchange` event is firing before the `.validate()` method is called.  Never mind, as long as you're happy with your solution.

Comment: That I don't know. Might be a bug in the widget. Even if it were fixed it wouldn't matter. I still want a way to validate the input if and only if it's under jquery validation. The default behavior of .valid to just randomly add validation doesn't make sense to me.